# airodump can't detect networks

Tags: aircrack-ng

I am using `airodump` and on Bionic 18.04 these are the commands that I have executed as root:

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 down
iwconfig wlp3s0 mode monitor 
ifconfig wlp3s0 up
airmon-ng check wlp3s0
kill networkmanger (it's number)
kill dhclient (it's number)
kill wpa-supplicant (it's number)
systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
kill avahi-daemon (it's number)
airodump-ng wlp3s0
```

and I got this message although I did disconnect the wireless from any WiFi access points:

> airodump failed Device or resource busy

*How should I fix this?*

Comment: Codename: bionic
#35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018

Comment: No i didn't ...

Comment: i have tried to try disconnecting the WiFi adapter from any wireless network and the same thing happened

Comment: I'm all out of ideas but have incorporated our conversation into the question itself and deleted my comments to keep things tidy here.  You should do the same as now it looks like you're talking to yourself.  **;-)**

Comment: Any one help please.

Comment: One last try: what is the output of `iwconfig wlan0 mode master`?